# Can you make population inferences from two different samples of the same population?

Tags: inference, population

Say that 100 police-trained dogs were chosen and randomly divided into two groups. One group would be kept with trainers who don't expect the dogs to get too trained and the second group is kept with trainers that believe in the dogs and know they can get trained even further.
After a month both groups were tested and the group of dogs with the trainers who believed in them were much better at doing what they were trained for.
Could you make population inferences?
Why or why not?

I think that you could as you used the 100 and that's your population but I'm not sure.

edit:

The dogs were randomly chosen as well. Then the 100 dogs were randomly divided into groups of 50. So 2 groups in total.

Comment: You have a sample of 100 randomly divided into two groups (equal? you don't say) given different treatments. (Where does the 200 figure come from?) That's fine in itself: indeed such subdivision as part of an experimental design is good practice. The major question is how were the 100 chosen in the first place. If they are not a random sample from some larger population, it's hard to see what you can infer towards.

Comment: Students? Dogs? Which is it?

Comment: dogs, my bad...

Comment: @Nick: It's hard, but most studies are like that - could you get a random sample from all the police dogs in the world? Subject-matter knowledge is used to infer to wider populations.

Comment: @Hax: From what population were the dogs randomly chosen? You can make population inferences about that population easily; to generalize to all police dogs, to all dogs, or to students relies on making assumptions about how similar they are.

Comment: @Scortchi I agree with the main point you are making, but your example is a straw dog argument. The research problem is more likely to be something like "what can we say about police dogs trained by this organisation, or in this city?", not in the whole wide world. I wouldn't rule out the idea that sampling from such a group can be well done. It's for the researcher to focus on what the precise aim is; we agree on that.

Comment: @Nick: The sample might be from the population of dogs available for training in this organization on Thursday, 3rd October, 2013; the research question is likely to pertain to a somewhat wider population. The point I wanted to make was that "the population of interest" is usually an idealization applied to any physically realizable sampling scheme & inference relies partly on assumptions of generalizability; you can even take the approach of forgetting about sampling & base inference solely on the random assignment of treatments to available cases.

Comment: I agree with that. I think it's consistent with my more elliptical statement "If they are not a random sample from some larger population, it's hard to see what you can infer towards". Even if one prefers to forget about sampling, random assignment of treatments within the available data can't compensate for poor sampling, as I see it. This is an example of a problem still being a problem even if you would prefer not to focus on it.

Comment: @Nick: And I agree with that; it's easy to overlook that, however good the experimental design,  generalization needs more theoretical support & corroborative evidence the further it moves from the population actually sampled. [Example.](http://www2.psych.ubc.ca/~ara/media/WEIRDinScience.pdf)